# Moodle object storage file system "No candidate objects found"

Tags: php, amazon-s3, filesystems, storage, moodle

So I've been trying to see if the plugins I've installed for moodle ([moodle-tool_objectfs](https://github.com/catalyst/moodle-tool_objectfs/blob/master/lang/en/tool_objectfs.php))

is working correctly. It seems like the cronjob is working perfectly but whenever I uploaded any files (etc : sample.png), it's still not stored in s3. When i check the logs in the task_log it says

> Execute scheduled task: Object file system upload task (tool_objectfs\task\push_objects_to_storage)
>   ... started 10:51:02. Current memory use 32.1MB.
>   No candidate objects found.
>   ... used 1 dbqueries
>   ... used 0.0039408206939697 seconds
>   Scheduled task complete: Object file system upload task (tool_objectfs\task\push_objects_to_storage)

Here's is my config for the plugin 
[image: moo]

Why is it saying

> No candidate objects found.

Did i miss anything or is my setup wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm. I've fixed it by setting the Min. Age to 0 seconds.

[Minimum age that a object must exist on the local filedir before it will be considered for transfer](https://moodle.org/plugins/tool_objectfs)

Comment: I am using the same plugin, but couldn't make it work. All the media and files are broken. May I know your configuration?

Comment: See if you can answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69821065/migrate-moodle-data-to-amazon-s3