# Migrate moodle data to Amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3, moodle

I have migrated moodle data directory to Amazon s3. Now I am trying to access all the files from the s3 storage using this plugin [moodle-tool_objectfs](https://github.com/catalyst/moodle-tool_objectfs)

Attaching my settings screenshot. I am trying to access all the media files amazon s3 instead from server file system. Example, site logo, course materials in PDF format, etc.,

[image]

Comment: This is a contributed plugin rather than a core Moodle plugin. It's developed by Catalyst IT who are a great open source company though - they are usually very responsive to questions. Maybe raise this as an issue here - https://github.com/catalyst/moodle-tool_objectfs/issues

Comment: @RussellEngland Before I raise some issue, I wanted to make sure I am done things right. You have any experience with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the shout-out Russell!

It sounds like you have manually migrated the content to S3 rather than relying on this plugin to do the work for you. I'd guess that your manual migration has put the files into a structure/path that the plugin isn't expecting. especially if you have copied your complete moodledata folder into S3 and not just the uploaded user files. (The tool_objectfs plugin does not replace the need for a normal moodledata directory, it just allows the majority of your files to be stored in S3.)

Usually you would have a Moodle site set up with a normal moodledata directory and then you would install our tool_objectfs plugin which would migrate files from moodledata to your s3 storage, relying on the plugin to perform the migration for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making me understand this.. My moodle data directory size is of more than 200GB and it is in production. I need to replicate the same in test site to make sure things are good before making changes in production. In that case moving moodle data directory is cost effective. So, we planned a manual migration to S3 and point it there. Is this something we cannot achieve?

Comment: I'm not aware of anyone who has used our plugin to migrate it that way - it's possible, but will be a bit of work for you to understand how it all works first.

You would be better to test it out first on a smaller sized site so you understand it works - then drop the plugin into prod, migrate all the files, and then point your testing site at the same s3 storage with a read-only user as per:
https://github.com/catalyst/moodle-tool_objectfs#sharing-files-across-moodles-to-save-disk

Comment: How do I make sure CRON is running? I couldn't see any files/directories copied to my s3 instance. You have any documentation to setup CRON?

Comment: Setting up Moodle's cron process is really well documented in the Moodle installation docs and is not something I can prsonally help you with - probably best that you look at the install docs, and the scheduled task reports within moodle to see which tasks are running when. Keep in mind that this tool is not designed to upload everything all at once and will require you to have the cron process running properly and make progress overnight. As you might be able to tell - I'm not much of an SO user, but there is a lot of help in the community forums on moodle.org too. Good luck!